# Training neural network using particle swarm optimization in matlab

Tags: neural-network, matlab, particle-swarm

I want to train a neural network using Particle Swarm Optimization algorithm, but matlab toolbox doesn't have any function for train network with this algorithm, I've searched and founded some PSO toolboxes but they didn't work. Can anybody help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use George Ever's toolbook for trainng neural network using PSO: 
http://www.georgeevers.org/pso_research_toolbox.htm

and download tricia sample code: 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29565-neural-network-add-in-for-psort


hope it helps, :)