# integrate BP neural network with PSO

Tags: matlab, neural-network, prediction, backpropagation, particle-swarm

I would like to use PSO to optimize BP neural network weights for prediction of breast cancer on Matlab.
 there is no option in the neural toolbox to do that. and after searching, i found the memetic approach but I don't now how to use it throw Matlab.
 can anybody help me?
thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Training neural network using particle swarm optimization in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643305/training-neural-network-using-particle-swarm-optimization-in-matlab)

Comment: Have you looked into the duplicate question? Your exact question was answered there. There is also a sample code provided!